# Can a file have localization on MacOS from a Xcode project

Tags: macos, cocoa, localization, nsfilemanager

What I mean is this: I am developing a course. I have 10 files that I want to provide to the user as free. Files that the user may use to follow the course. The problem is that the course is multi-language, so, suppose the files are musics.

So, when the user clicks a button, all these musics are copied from the bundle to a directory on the user's computer. That folder will open automatically and the user will see the files there but they will have the name I have assigned originally to them in one language. I want a file called "music1.mp3", for example, be seen by portuguese-speakers like "música1.mp3", for example.

OK, I know. I can copy the files to the directory them rename them on-the-fly to the correspondent language, getting their names from `Localizable.strings` but I wonder if there is a way to add localization internally to the files, so if the user drags them between computers with different languages they will show with a different name, according to the computer's default language, provided that I have localized for that language. My idea is, always appear in english, unless I have localized for that specific language.

I know apple does that for specific directories of MacOS, like Pictures, Movies, etc., that appear with another names if I change MacOS language.

Is there a way to do that? or will I have to use of renaming the whole thing after copying?

Comment: yup localizable strings is the correct place for this, that is the same method that os x uses to translate Library to Biblioteca... if you have an interface that displays them, you could leave the file the same name and have a display name per lang...

Comment: @GradyPlayer - what do you mean? As I copy the files I consult the localizable strings file to copy it with the localized name? It appears to me that you are not talking about this.

Comment: so on a spanish language Finder, it will display Library as Biblioteca but that is just a display name (if you have an interface for display)... if you need the actual file to be a different name you could consult a strings file and copy to that name, or copy to the normal name and symlink to the localized name...

Comment: ok thanks!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, I don't think this is possible.

The localization of directory names like `Library` happens at the system level -- those directories are flagged as having localized names (by putting a hidden file named `.localized` in them!), and the system looks up the appropriate name in a system strings file.

As far as I'm aware, there is no supported way to add extra directory names to this localization table, nor is there any way to localize the name of a plain file.

Comment: thanks. I was just asking to make sure I was not missing something.